# Solving $\int\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{1-\frac{1}{x}}\;dx$ in the simplest way

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to solve a problem in my book:

> $$\int\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{1-\frac{1}{x}}\;dx$$

I am trying to do this without using any techniques (eg. no u-sub, no parts...) just using what I know about basic integrals, by inspection. I tried to pull the denominator into the numerator to get some constant that I can pull in front of the integrand, but I have been unsuccessful. I am looking to see how I should simplify this and break it apart into smaller integrals that are easy to compute.
Thank You.

Comment: Try multiplying top and bottom with $x$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer has already been given; this one encompasses a few of the remarks and subtleties.

Note that:
$$\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{1-\frac{1}{x}}$$
is defined for $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \left\{ 0,1 \right\}$. For $x \ne 0$, rewrite:
$$\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{1-\frac{1}{x}} = \frac{\frac{1}{x}}{1-\frac{1}{x}}\frac{x}{x}=\frac{1}{x-1}$$
Now notice that:

- for $x>1$, you have:
  $$\bigl( \ln(x-1) \bigr)' = \frac{1}{x-1}$$
- for $x<1$, you have:
  $$\bigl( \ln(1-x) \bigr)' = \frac{-1}{1-x} = \frac{1}{x-1}$$

This is often abbreviated as:
$$\int \frac{1}{x-1} \,\mbox{d}x = \ln\left| x-1 \right| + C$$
but the following would be more accurate:
$$\int \frac{\frac{1}{x}}{1-\frac{1}{x}} \,\mbox{d}x =
\begin{cases}
\ln(x-1) + C_1 & \mbox{for } x > 1 \\
\ln(1-x) + C_2 & \mbox{for } 0 < x < 1 \\
\ln(1-x) + C_3 & \mbox{for } x < 0 \\
\end{cases}$$
In this way, you have the set of *all possible* anti-derivatives (since the constants need not be the same on the different intervals of the domain), which is what is usually meant with the "indefinite integral".

Of course for any definite integral on an interval $[a,b]$ not containing $x=0$ and $x=1$, you pick an appropriate anti-derivative.

Comment: +1 for the more accurate version. Usually one actually knows what interval one is working in, and in my experience students often get confused about that absolute value appearing in some sense from nowhere...

Comment: @mickep I agree; in the standard tables of primitives, students very often have to 'swallow' (and memorize by heart) $\int \tfrac{1}{x} \,\mbox{d}x = \ln|x|+C$ without explanation while it definitely deserves some explanation.

Answer (score 10):

Your function is

$$f (x)=\frac {1}{x-1} $$

the anti-derivative is

$$F (x)=\ln (|x-1|)+C. $$

$F $ is defined in an interval which doesn't contain neither $0$ nor $1$.

Comment: I believe the OP want to know _how_ to compute the integral.

Comment: As a nearly irrelevant nit, one need also assume $x \neq 0, 1$ anywhere in the domain of integration.

Comment: By inspection you can take $\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{1-\frac{1}{x}}$ and multiply by $1=\frac{x}{x}$ resulting in the function $f(x)$ that Salahamam_Fatima gave. No need to keep the 'odd form' of the function when it is literally equivalent to $1/{(x-1)}$

Comment: Ahh thank you, I forgot about thinking of 1 as x/x. Much appreciated everyone.

Comment: @jorgeegroj It is not literally equivalent at all. The two expression have different domains. As written, the domain excludes both $0$ and $1$ but in the new form, the domain only must exclude $1$, so ALB is quite correct.

Comment: yeah, as far as domains go I guess you're right @TheCount. However, other than that it is exactly the same function and you could restrict the domain on mine to make it equivalent. If anything mine is more 'general' than the one provided and behaves the same everywhere where the one in the question is defined.

(additionally, you could use the form $x/{x*(x-1)}$ and have it be the exact same function with the exact same implied domain).

Comment: Sure, but you have to specify!

Comment: Why should one exclude $x=0$ from the domain ?The singularity has null measure so that the integral is defined.

Comment: @YvesDaoust cause of the initial expression of $f (x) $

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima: I don't agree, IMO the integral is defined anyway.

Comment: @YvesDaoust even for $x=1$ ?

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima: did I ever mention $x=1$ ? I am speaking of $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The given function can be simplified like this:

f(x) = 1/(x-1)

The integral of this is

F(x) = ln|x-1| + C.  
Where x is not defined for 0 or 1.

This is the easiest method for this integral.